# Nonhyperelliptic curves of genus 3.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I am reading Vakil's algebraic geometry. There is exercise:

> Show that the nonhyperelliptic curves of genus 3 form a family of dimension 6.

Then there is a hint: counting the dimension of the family of regular quartic curves, and quotient by $\mathrm{Aut} \mathbb{P}^{2}=\mathrm{PGL}(3)$. (We know that , there is a bijection between nonhyperelliptic genus $3$ curves,
and plane quartic curves up to projective linear transformations)

But the dimension of the family of regular quartic curves is $\binom{6}{2}=15$, and $\mathrm{dim} \mathrm{Aut} \mathbb{P}^{2}=9-1=8$, so I think the dimension of the family should be 7 instead of 6? Is it right? If not, could you tell me where I make a mistake? Thank you very much.

Comment: Although there are $15$ coefficients that you can play with when defining a quartic curve, note that multiplying them all by a constant doesn't change the curve. This is the "extra dimension" you are missing.

Comment: Oh, I understand. Thank you!!